# How do i override a Laravel Nova controller?

Tags: laravel, controller, overriding

Because Laravel Nova global search ignores policies, i want to override it's controller. Somehow this doesn't work and the global search defaults to `Laravel\Nova\Http\Controllers\SearchController`.

What i have so far:

`app/config.php`

```php
    //..
    'providers' => [

        //..
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\NovaServiceProvider::class,
       //..
    ],
```

(please note the order of the providers)

`routes/web.php`

```php
//..
Route::get('nova-api/search', 'SearchController@index');
```

`app/Http/Controllers/SearchController.php`

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Laravel\Nova\Nova;
use Laravel\Nova\GlobalSearch;
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest;
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Controllers\SearchController as NovaSearchController;

class SearchController extends NovaSearchController
{
    /**
     * Get the global search results for the given query.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return (new GlobalSearch(
            $request, Nova::globallySearchableResources($request)
        ))->get();
    }
}
```

**Versions**

- Laravel Version: 5.8.24
- Nova Version: 2.0.6
- PHP Version: 7.2.10

This does not work. The route `nova-api/search` still points to `Laravel\Nova\Http\Controllers\SearchController`. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, here's how I solved it.

In AppServiceProvider.php added the following code to the boot method:

```
$this->app->bind(
   NovaController::class, 
   YourController::class
);
```

[Here's the description of how it works](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations)